# Code is not displaying JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, parsing, httprequest

Hey guys I am trying to make a request to a JSON page, grabbing the data, then displaying it to my console but it is giving me "undefined". Why is that?

Here is the code and then the JSON page will be posted under it:

```
(function Apod() {
    var api_key = 'NNKOjkoul8n1CH1NoUFo',
        url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod' + "?api_key=" + api_key,
        data;
    var apodRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    apodRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (apodRequest.readyState === 4 && apodRequest.status === 200) {
            var response = apodRequest.responseText;
            var parsedAPOD = JSON.parse(response);
            data += parsedAPOD;
            for (i = 0; i < parsedAPOD.length; i++) {
                data += parsedAPOD[i];
                console.log("Parsing lines: <br>" + parsedAPOD[i]);
            }

        }
        apodRequest.open("GET", url, true);
        apodRequest.send(null);
    }
}());
```

JSON page parsing:

```
{
  "date": "2016-11-05",
  "explanation": "Shot in Ultra HD, this stunning video can take you on a tour of the International Space Station. A fisheye lens with sharp focus and extreme depth of field provides an immersive visual experience of life in the orbital outpost. In the 18 minute fly-through, your point of view will float serenely while you watch our fair planet go by 400 kilometers below the seven-windowed Cupola, and explore the interior of the station's habitable nodes and modules from an astronaut's perspective. The modular International Space Station is Earth's largest artificial satellite, about the size of a football field in overall length and width. Its total pressurized volume is approximately equal to that of a Boeing 747 aircraft.",
  "media_type": "video",
  "service_version": "v1",
  "title": "ISS Fisheye Fly-Through",
  "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/DhmdyQdu96M?rel=0"
}
```

Comment: What exactly is showing undefined? The response is an object, not an array, so it doesn't have a length. The loop shouldn't run at all.

Comment: Is `parsedAPOD` an array? So use `for in` instead.

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer [do not use `for...in`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: it's hard to tell because of your indenting, but `apodRequest.open(...)` is inside the `onreadystatechange` handler so will never get executed

Comment: @vlaz above xhr response is an object and not an array.

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer I thought you were suggesting `for...in` if it was an array. Apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: @vlaz don't apologies you was right :)

Comment: @Chris test this https://jsfiddle.net/MamdouhFreelancer/1then2fk/

Answer (score 2):

You have a few errors in your code.

First off, the general structure of it should be like this

```
(function Apod() {
    var api_key = 'NNKOjkoul8n1CH1NoUFo',
        url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod' + "?api_key=" + api_key,
        data;
    var apodRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    apodRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //Code here
    };
    apodRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    apodRequest.send(null);
}());
```

Notice how I moved `apodRequest.open("GET", url, true);` and `apodRequest.send(null);` outside of the `onreadystatechange` handler.

Secondly, instead of

```
apodRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (apodRequest.readyState === 4 && apodRequest.status === 200) {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

you can simply do

```
apodRequest.onload = function() {
        //Code here
};
```

As it's the event that will fire when a response is returned. So you don't need the `if` check inside.

Finally, inside the `onload` handler, you have a few mistakes, such as:

- `data += parsedAPOD;` this is wrong because `data` is an <strike>object</strike> `undefined` up to this point and `parsedAPOD` is an object. <strike>Doing `+=` between two objects will not merge them. If you want to merge two objects there are other ways, e.g. [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)</strike>
- `for (i = 0; i < parsedAPOD.length; i++) { ... }` is wrong because `parsedAPOD` is an object. Objects do not have a `length` property, so this is not the correct way to iterate over it. Use [`for ... in ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop instead
- `data += parsedAPOD[i];` is, again, wrong, because this is not the way to merge objects.
- `parsedAPOD[i]` is wrong because `i` is an integer, in this case, so `parsedAPOD[i]` is simply undefined.

Hope this analysis helps you correct your code.

Answer (score 1):

first of all `parsedAPOD` is an object and `parsedAPOD.length` is not valid. You can use `for in` loop to iterate through an object as below.

```
for (var i in parsedAPOD) {
    data += parsedAPOD[i];
    console.log("Parsing lines: <br>" + parsedAPOD[i]);
}
```